# JSON synchronized Dictionary in Python : dealing with temporary references

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am writing a class that acts as a dictionary but saves its content to a json file each time a modification is made to ensure a synchronous state.

However I stumbled upon a special case that breaks my synchronization : when appending a value to a list inside the dictionary.
Since this uses `__getitem__`, how can I make sure that if the item returned is modified, I save it to the JSON file ?

Here is a fully functional code snippet (Python 3.9.2) to illustrate what I mean

```
import json


class SyncDictJSON(dict):
    __instances: dict = {}

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, filepath: str, **kwargs):
        if filepath not in SyncDictJSON.__instances:
            SyncDictJSON.__instances[filepath] = cls(filepath, **kwargs)
        return SyncDictJSON.__instances[filepath]

    def __init__(self, filepath: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.update(SyncDictJSON.read_data_from_filename(self.filepath))

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print(f"getitem {item}")
        return super(SyncDictJSON, self).__getitem__(item)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f"set item {key},{value}")
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        SyncDictJSON.write_data_to_filename(self, self.filepath)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        super().__delitem__(key)
        SyncDictJSON.write_data_to_filename(self, self.filepath)

    @staticmethod
    def write_data_to_filename(data, filepath: str):
        with open(filepath, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            json.dump(data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

    @staticmethod
    def read_data_from_filename(filename: str):
        with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            return json.load(file)

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, filepath):
        return cls(filepath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("testing.json", "w") as file:
        file.write("{}")
    dico = SyncDictJSON.create("testing.json")

    dico["a_list"] = []
    dico["a_list"].append(5)

    print(dico)  # {'a_list': [5]} but testing.json will be empty
```

Comment: I am curious if there is a clever way to achieve this, but you don't really have control over somebody at any time changing the list object that also happens to be referenced as a value in your container. Maybe you can catch if a mutable object is stored in your container, you equip it with some event mechanism (recursively, if the mutable object itself contains mutable objects, like lists of lists) that notifies your container class.

Comment: your code doent work with mw (dont know why ) random changes produced the right output but no sure how.

Comment: Nevertheless try dico["a_list"] = 5 and see if it works

Comment: @pipo1980 Well this code finishes with exit code 0 for me. dico["a_list"] = 5 will work but the problem is that I want changes to the object inside the dictionaries to trigger a save. The comment above yours seems to be a good start in case anyone wants the challenge

Comment: to me  dico["a_list"] = 5 works. I mean I have the json file with empty key that is filled with   dico["a_list"] = 5, problem is that your working code doesnt work and gives FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'testing.json' error if no file is present or JSONDecodeError: Expecting value error if empty blank file is present, so the 'fully functional code snippet' isnt working if you dont give us the starting json file we can't test your code

Comment: Yeah that's true, my bad i'll edit to add the creation of the file
The problem I meant is not that the code won't execute tho, but it is now added it should work even when testing.json is not present on the file system

Comment: Actually I made it work deleting the def Create(.. part and adding some try: except: in def read_data_from_filename  and in def  __init__ and removing __instances: dict = {}

Comment: Oh that's probably because we don't have the same version, I added my python version in the question

Comment: does  <__instances: dict = {}> equals to < __instances  = {} >  ?

Comment: `a_variable: dict` is just typing hint for the IDE

Comment: why callng __instances:  a class attributre ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SyncDictJSON` object will record changes to the dictionary. However, once
the list for `a_list` is created, appending to it will not change the dictionary;
the dictionary will contain a reference to a list `[5]`, which is still the same
reference as when that list was empty.

To record appending to the list, too, you could use the following code, which
wraps the class `list` into a similar wrapper. It relies on a reference to the
synchronized dictionary being passed down to the list, so it will require a
little extra space. If you're planning to delete list items and/or insert them,
you would need to overwrite those methods in `SyncList`, too.

```
import json

class SyncList(list):
    def __init__(self, container, *args, **kwargs):
        print('list init', *args, **kwargs)
        self._container = container
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def append(self, x):
        print('list.append', self, x)
        super().append(x)
        self._container.write_data_to_filename(
            self._container, self._container.filepath)


class SyncDictJSON(dict):
    __instances: dict = {}

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, filepath: str, **kwargs):
        if filepath not in SyncDictJSON.__instances:
            SyncDictJSON.__instances[filepath] = cls(filepath, **kwargs)
        return SyncDictJSON.__instances[filepath]

    def __init__(self, filepath: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.update(SyncDictJSON.read_data_from_filename(self.filepath))

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print(f"getitem {item}")
        return super(SyncDictJSON, self).__getitem__(item)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f"set item {key},{value}")
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        SyncDictJSON.write_data_to_filename(self, self.filepath)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        super().__delitem__(key)
        SyncDictJSON.write_data_to_filename(self, self.filepath)

    @staticmethod
    def write_data_to_filename(data, filepath: str):
        with open(filepath, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            json.dump(data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

    @staticmethod
    def read_data_from_filename(filename: str):
        with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            return json.load(file)

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, filepath):
        return cls(filepath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("testing.json", "w") as file:
        file.write("{}")
    dico = SyncDictJSON.create("testing.json")
    dico["a_list"] = SyncList(dico, [])
    dico["a_list"].append(5)
    print(dico)  # {'a_list': [5]}; testing.json will have the same
# list init []
# set item a_list,[]
# getitem a_list
# list.append [] 5
# {'a_list': [5]}
```

Comment: That's a good idea, I think it sums up the answer. The best implementation would be to do that for all mutable types as Dr. V said but this should work for me :D

Comment: @VirtualScooter , I've been playing with subclassed dict to try to understand initial question. In my code I can trigger saving the modified dict to file with just using: print(dico['a_list']). But still can't catch why dico[''a_list'].append(7) doesn't trigger the getitem or setitem that in my case dump the data to json file. OK I get 'the dictionary will contain a reference to a list [5], which is still the same reference as when that list was empty' but is there any kind of dictionary method that says refresh this reference that could be called after appending ?

Comment: @pippo1980 `dico['a_list'].append(5)` **does** trigger get item, the problem is that the get item gets triggered when executing `dico['a_list']`, so before the append, so the item is still the same

Comment: Ok thanks more clear to me now. So only way to have my JSON constantly updated is to call a dict key value after any change on the dict itself ?